# Receive global TouchEvents with NSEvent

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I just try to receive Touch Events globally in the Window and not only in a view.
In my code, you can see below, i will get the absolute position of the touch in the magic trackpad. As long as the cursor is inside the view (the red NSRect) it works fine, but how can i receive touches outside of this view. 
I searched for solutions in many communities and the apple devcenter but found nothing.
I think the problem is this: `NSSet *touches = [ev touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseTouching inView:nil];` Isn't there a method in NSEvent that gets every touch?

Hope anybody can help me.

Here my Implementation:

```
@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        [self setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES];
        myColor  = [NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:1.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    // Drawing code here.
    NSRect bounds = [self bounds];

    [myColor set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];

}

- (void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)ev {
    NSSet *touches = [ev touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseTouching inView:nil];

    for (NSTouch *touch in touches) {

        NSPoint fraction = touch.normalizedPosition;
        NSSize whole = touch.deviceSize;
        NSPoint wholeInches = {whole.width / 72.0, whole.height / 72.0};
        NSPoint pos = wholeInches;
        pos.x *= fraction.x;
        pos.y *= fraction.y;
        NSLog(@"%s: Finger is touching %g inches right and %g inches up "
              @"from lower left corner of trackpad.", __func__, pos.x, pos.y);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `touchesMatchingPhase:inView:` with `nil` for the last parameter (the way you are doing) will get all touches. The problem is that `touchesBeganWithEvent:` will simply not fire for a control that isn't in the touch area.

You can make the view the first responder, which will send all events to it first. See [becomeFirstResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/becomeFirstResponder) and [Responder object](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html)